# Getting formatted result with nested arrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate `sql` statement dynamically with loops but i am not getting any idea on how to do it with html name array.
assuming `$name` and `$message` are post arrays ... and assuming length of both will be equal,
following is a method i tried;

```
<?php 
 $name = array('name1','name2' );
 $mess= array('message1','message2' );
 $values = array($name,$mess);
  foreach ($values as $key){ 
    foreach ($key as $value){
     echo $value.","; 
      } 
     } 
 ?>
```

output is =

> name1,name2,message1,message2,

but i want output as =

> (name1,message1),(name2,message2),

**Edit :** I have acess to `$values` only and I will not be able to determine how many values are going to join in `$values` ..
 like it can be

`$values=array($name,$message,$phone);`

and the result i want will be

```
(name1,message1,phone1),(name2,message2,phone2)
```

Comment: So add `echo "("` where you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solutions is

**Step 1:** Loop your `$values` this will gonna loop every index of your array like `$name`

```
foreach($name as $index => $value) {
    // do something
}
```

**Step 2:** Inside your loop values start with `(` which mean wrap your detail in `(`

```
echo "(";
```

**Step 3:** loop parent array

```
foreach($values as $key => $arr) {
    // do something
}
```

**Step 4:** Inside the loop of your parent array display each data according to your index

```
echo $values[$key][$index];
```

`$key` represents the index of your `parent` array while `$index` represents the index of your child array like `$name`

this loop will create data like

```
(name1,message1,phone1)
```

and I just add this

```
if ($key < sizeof(array_keys($values))-1) {
  echo ",";
}
```

to avoid adding `,` after the last loop

> This code will dynamically display array you put inside `$values`

So your code would be like this

```
$name = array('name1','name2','name3','name4' );
$mess= array('message1','message2','message3','message4' );
$phone= array('phone1','phone2','phone3','phone4' );
$married= array('yes','no','yes','yes' );
$values = array($name,$mess,$phone);
foreach($name as $index => $value) {
    echo "(";
    foreach($values as $key => $arr) {
        echo $values[$key][$index];
        if ($key < sizeof(array_keys($values))-1) {
          echo ",";
        }
    }
    echo "),";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/693028)

or this

```
$name = array('name1','name2','name3','name4' );
$mess= array('message1','message2','message3','message4' );
$phone= array('phone1','phone2','phone3','phone4' );
$values = array($name,$mess,$phone);
foreach($name as $index => $value) {
    $join = array();
    foreach($values as $key => $arr) {
      $join[] = $values[$key][$index];
    }
    echo "(".implode(",",$join)."),";
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/693088)

Comment: $name = array('name1','name2','name3','name4' );
$mess= array('message1','message2','message3','message4' );
$phone= array('phone1','phone2','phone3','phone4' );

$calc_var = count($name);
$values = array($name,$mess,$phone);

for ($i=0; $i < $calc_var; $i++) {
  echo "(";
  foreach($values as $key => $arr) {
      echo $values[$key][$i];
      if ($key < sizeof(array_keys($values))-1) {
        echo ",";
      }
  }
  echo "),";
}

this is also working .... what should be the preference ??a for loop or a foreach loop  ??

Comment: Use foreach its much faster

Answer (score 0):

```
 $name = array('name1','name2' );
 $mess = array('message1','message2' );

 foreach ($names as $k => $v){
     echo "(".$v.",".$mess[$k]."),";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you not need two foreach loop, only use foreach loop and pass key to other array and get value

```
$name = array('name1','name2' );
$mess= array('message1','message2' );
$values = array($name,$mess);
foreach ($name as $keys => $vals)
{ 
    echo "(".$vals.",".$mess[$keys]."),"; 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/692914)**

Comment: one problem what if the array contains more than 2 values

Comment: i have acess to $values only ... i will not be able to determine how many values are going to join in $values .. like it can be $values=array($name,$message,$phone);
and the result i want will be (name1,message1,phone1),(name2,message2,phone2)

Comment: exactly @NewbeeDev

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrap_map() function in order to join two array. Here is reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
 <?php
     $name = array('name1','name2' );
     $mess= array('message1','message2' );

     $value = array_map(null, $name, $mess);
     print_r($value);

 ?>
```